# AWS 504 Gateway timeout on Laravel Application

Tags: amazon-web-services

What we need to consider when lunching a Laravel Application on the AWS server?

I have the local version, with same database and code base, but the page the through 504 error on the online server loading in 1.5 second in my local ENV, with 8GB memory.

We upgraded the AWS server to t3.large, but same result and the page load time is 1 minute and randomly through 504 error.

so what config missed here that my local env is much faster than the AWS server?

Comment: Most likely something is misconfigured as EC2 should be about the same performance as your local machine - but adding latency. Impossible to say what as you have provided very little information.

Comment: Are you trying it behind corporate network? Could be proxy or even your company not whitelisting the ec2 address space (like in my case). You could try to reach it from a different network, like cellular from your phone.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, it is wired as I didn't know how to specify it, but looks it was the Laravel problem and as I used  wherenotin it caused the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570755/very-slow-query-when-using-eloquent-wherenotin